# Full size background without resizing

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm facing this trouble for quite some time now, have tried n number of options but still no luck.
I have this background image :

[image: background image]

Which I want to make as the background of my website. I added it as a full sized background, but I don't know why it always gets resized and becomes something like this.

[image: resized image]

Here's my css code for the background image.

```
body
{
  background: url('../images/home.jpg') no-repeat   center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

I'm really unsure how to fix this! Please guide me in the correct way.

Comment: When you are setting it do background-size: cover - you are saying stretch this over whatever size the background is.

Comment: @ajmajmajma
I only added that line so that the background covers the entire screen.

Comment: No I know - I'm saying that is why it is stretching. In other words this is how cover is intended to work.

Comment: Okay, removed that. Still the same.

Comment: If you don't want it to stretch, you could use background-size: contain.

Comment: You can use background-size: contain - but it will keep the image scaled to it's proportions. So at odd sizes you will have white space around it.

Comment: My two cents  - there's really no need for using prefixes with background properties...

Answer (score 1):

The `background-size: cover` property in CSS3 stretches your images to fit the background of the element you have specified, which in this case your body.

**Edit:**  As others have mentioned, using `background-size: contain` would give you the most desirable result as it is defined by the following:

**contain**
This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.

The link below also has other properties that may give you your desired results:
Source:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Removed that, still no luck.

Comment: Did you removed all 4?

Comment: If you do not want it to stretch, use contain as I have mentioned in my edit.  This will leave you with the white spaces around the image. If you want the image to cover the entire screen suggest you get the image at a higher resolution and size in order for it to fit on most screens.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `background-size:contain` instead of `background-size:cover`. Maybe that is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, split the `background` property for each sub-attribute :

```
body
{
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQinh.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/j0n19rw5/1/

#### Edit:

Add this to your CSS since your HTML/body seem to have a low height:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
```

Comment: This is what I see : http://i.imgur.com/5ZzWajw.jpg It's strange because your HTML and BODY tag have a 435px height...and I don't find out why.

Comment: Edited my answer... Test it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your image in proportion you would want to use

```
background-size: contain;
```

However the issue with this is it will keep the background in proportion, so if your window is not the same proportions you will have white space around. Building off @Sebastien 's fiddle  I can show you what I mean -

http://jsfiddle.net/j0n19rw5/5/

You could try re-sizing  the image itself to work better with contain.

But if you want it to cover the background you would probably be best using cover. One trick is to crop the image to the space (if you know a general sizing).

You can get away without stretching it too much with a method like this one :

https://jsfiddle.net/r3qpe4dm/1/

But it will still cut off your image at smaller sizes.